# recyclerView can't click item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I can't click an item on my recyclerview, i think my code is just fine

Mainactivity

```
public class Appetizer extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final  int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdapterFood mAdapter;
    List<DataFood> data=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appetizer);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    new AsyncFetch().execute();

   }



   private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
       ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(Appetizer.this);
       HttpURLConnection conn;
       URL url = null;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute(){
           super.onPreExecute();

           pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
           pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
           pdLoading.show();

       }

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                url = new URL("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/private_html/shAppetizer.php");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }

            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            }  catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }
           try {

               int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

               // Check if successful connection made
               if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                   // Read data sent from server
                   InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                   String line;

                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                       result.append(line);
                   }

                   // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                   return (result.toString());

               } else {

                   return ("unsuccessful");
               }

           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return e.toString();
           } finally {
               conn.disconnect();
           }


       }


       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           //this method will be running on UI thread

           pdLoading.dismiss();
           List<DataFood> data=new ArrayList<>();

           pdLoading.dismiss();
           try {

               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
               for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                   JSONArray innerArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                   for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++){
                       JSONObject json_data = innerArray.getJSONObject(j);
//                 JSONArray foodArray= json_data.getJSONArray("");
//                   for (int j=0;j<foodArray.length();j++){
                   DataFood foodData = new DataFood();

                       //JSONObject gambar = json_data.getJSONObject("gambar");
                   foodData.foodImage= json_data.getString("gambar");
                   foodData.foodName= json_data.getString("nama");
                   foodData.foodId= json_data.getInt("id");
                   foodData.price= json_data.getInt("harga");
                   data.add(foodData);
               }}
          // }

               recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lvaptzr);
               LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(Appetizer.this);
               recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
               //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Appetizer.this));
               mAdapter = new AdapterFood(Appetizer.this,data);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


           } catch (JSONException e) {
               Toast.makeText(Appetizer.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }}

}
```

and this is my Adapter

```
public class AdapterFood extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFood> data = Collections.emptyList();
    DataFood current;
    int currentPos=0;


    public AdapterFood(Context context, List<DataFood> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        Myholder holder=new Myholder(view);
        return holder;

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Myholder myholder=(Myholder) holder;
        DataFood current=data.get(position);
        myholder.textFoodname.setText(current.foodName);
        myholder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.price);
        myholder.textId.setText(String.valueOf(current.foodId));


      // Log.d("IMAGE_URL", "http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage);
       // Picasso.with(context).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage).into(myholder.ivFood);
        Glide.with(context).load(current.foodImage).asBitmap()
 //              .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).dontAnimate()
//                .error(R.mipmap.minus)
                .into(myholder.ivFood);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }



    class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textFoodname,textPrice,textId;
        ImageView ivFood;

        public Myholder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textFoodname=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFoodname);
            ivFood=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivFood);
            textId=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
            textPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        DataFood clickedDataItem = data.get(pos);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Order.class);
                        intent.putExtra("nama", data.get(pos).foodName);
                        intent.putExtra("harga", data.get(pos).price);
                        intent.putExtra("gambar", data.get(pos).foodImage);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"clicked" + clickedDataItem.foodName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"ga",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

AdapterLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivFood"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="id"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#666" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFoodname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textPrice"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="food name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="price"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kelompok3.restaurantapp.restoranfixx.Isimenu.Appetizer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lvaptzr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

i don't know why, i can't click the item. even the toast not showing up when i click the item. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: itemView.setOnClickListener... what is itemView from where you get this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below one

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Myholder myholder = (Myholder) holder;
    DataFood current = data.get(position);
    myholder.textFoodname.setText(current.foodName);
    myholder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.price);
    myholder.textId.setText(String.valueOf(current.foodId));

    Glide.with(context).load(current.foodImage).asBitmap()
            .into(myholder.ivFood);

    myholder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DataFood clickedDataItem = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Order.class);
            intent.putExtra("nama", data.get(position).foodName);
            intent.putExtra("harga", data.get(position).price);
            intent.putExtra("gambar", data.get(position).foodImage);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked" + clickedDataItem.foodName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

and update this on Myholder class

```
class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textFoodname, textPrice, textId;
    ImageView ivFood;
    CardView cardView;

    public Myholder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textFoodname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFoodname);
        ivFood = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFood);
        textId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
        textPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's same sir, cannot clicked

Comment: problem it that i have just call onclick on holder but it should be on myholder

Comment: i solved the problem from following your code and @sasikumar code. but the result just show the image not all of content sir

Comment: are u getting image from server or local just check out coz its not possible that image will come on one and doesn't come on other

Comment: from server sir, i think now the layout is the problem

Comment: just make adapter layout android:layout_height="390dp" to android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: the "harga" data it's not appeared

Comment: harga means price, that's integer type sir

Comment: so debug it and check that any value coming from server if its coming and not showing thn layout problem

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: foodsqlitedemo.quocnguyen.com.foodsqlitedemo, PID: 2663
                                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4e20

Answer (score 0):

setOnClickListener should be inside the onBindViewHolder method of RecyclerView.

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

   myholder.textFoodname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    DataFood clickedDataItem = data.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Order.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nama", data.get(position).foodName);
                    intent.putExtra("harga", data.get(position).price);
                    intent.putExtra("gambar", data.get(position).foodImage);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"clicked" + clickedDataItem.foodName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"ga",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

    });

}
```

Comment: but, getAdapterPosition(); is getting erro

Comment: you can directly  use position..thats in parameter (final int position)

Comment: how? sorry i'm new to android sir

Comment: final int pos = 0; like that? on bind method?

Comment: @sasikumar it will throw compile error just look before psoting

Comment: myholder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {. the myholder is getting error

Comment: @Fawwaz You can't set the Click Listener directly on the holder. You have to set it on one of the holder's views. In the answer above, the Click Listener is set on a view.

Answer (score 0):

You have made 2 clickable, thus not able to click the item.

```
Just remove one clickable from layout which is not using it, keep only the one which used in layout identifer:

 android:clickable="true"
```

> Note : in your case remove all

Comment: nice suggestion sir

Answer (score 0):

if you use recyclerView, you should try "callback interface" ;

**AdapterFood.class**

```
   public interface OnItemClickLitener {
      void onItemClick(View view, int position);
   }

   private OnItemClickLitener mOnItemClickLitener;

   public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickLitener mOnItemClickLitener) {
    this.mOnItemClickLitener = mOnItemClickLitener;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             mOnItemClickLitener. onItemClick();
        }
   }
```

**Myholder**

```
  class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textFoodname, textPrice, textId;
    ImageView ivFood;
    CardView cardView;

  public Myholder(View view) {
      super(view);
      textFoodname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFoodname);
      ivFood = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivFood);
      textId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textid);
      textPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
      cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
  }
}
```

**Appetizer**

```
   mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CourseListAdp.OnItemClickLitener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
         //your work
         int pos = position;
            if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
          **********
          **********
         }
     }
   }
```

Hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Youyr Layout File(remove clickable from yourlayout):

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#CCC"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ivFood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="id"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#666" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFoodname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textPrice"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivFood"
                android:text="food name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textPrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="price"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>

Change Your Adapter :

    public class AdapterFood extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFood.CustomViewHolder> {


    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFood> data = Collections.emptyList();


    public AdapterFood(Context context, List<DataFood> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterFood.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DataFood current = data.get(position);
        holder.textFoodname.setText(current.foodName);
        holder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.price);
        holder.textId.setText(String.valueOf(current.foodId));


        // Log.d("IMAGE_URL", "http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + current.foodImage).into(myholder.ivFood);
        Glide.with(context).load(current.foodImage).asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).dontAnimate()
                .error(R.mipmap.minus)
                .into(myholder.ivFood);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textFoodname, textPrice, textId;
        ImageView ivFood;


        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textFoodname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFoodname);
            ivFood = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFood);
            textId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textid);
            textPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(context, "ga" + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            int pos = getAdapterPosition();
            if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                DataFood clickedDataItem = data.get(pos);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Order.class);
                intent.putExtra("nama", data.get(pos).foodName);
                intent.putExtra("harga", data.get(pos).price);
                intent.putExtra("gambar", data.get(pos).foodImage);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked" + clickedDataItem.foodName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ga", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```